# Rest Assured Serenity getting Null point when move the environmental specific configuration to different class

Tags: rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I have set the URL  in the serenity.config and runnig the API resquest based on the regions.All are working fine but when i want to reduce the repeated codes as i have lot of apis to automate.
I tried to create a seperate class for {EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration} and tried to call in the test steps class getting null point.help me how can i reduce the code and make repeated thing in a reusable class.I am using retassured with serenity ,gradle

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);
LocalDate nextday = today.plusDays(2);
private EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables;
public Response response;
String basePath = "/booking/search";

@Step("user perform a GET search request current day")
public void SearchCurrentDay() {
    String BASEURI = EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(environmentVariables).getProperty("base.api.url");
    response = SerenityRest.given().contentType("application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .when().queryParam("type", 2)
            .queryParam("date_req", today.toString())
            .queryParam("days", 1)
            .queryParam("id", 1)
            .get(BASEURI + basePath);
    System.out.println("Search json response:::==>" + response.prettyPrint());  
}

@Step("user perform a GET diary search request Tomorrow")
public void dairySearchTomorrow() {
    String BASEURI = EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(environmentVariables).getProperty("base.api.url");
   response = SerenityRest.given().contentType("application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .when().queryParam("type", 2)
            .queryParam("date_req", tomorrow.toString())
            .get(BASEURI + basePath);
    System.out.println("search json response:::==>" + response.prettyPrint());
    
}

@Step("user perform a GET diary search request next day")
public void dairySearchNextDay() {
    String BASEURI = EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(environmentVariables).getProperty("base.api.url");
    response = SerenityRest.given().contentType("application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .when().queryParam("type", 2)
            .queryParam("date_req", nextday.toString())
            .get(BASEURI + basePath);
    System.out.println("search json response:::==>" + response.prettyPrint());

}
```

}

Comment: it's not enough to figure out what's wrong. Did you get NullPointerException? in which line? Please add stackstrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been Resolved as I used the:

```
String BASEURI = EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(environmentVariables).getProperty("base.api.url");
```

in @Before annotation to use it globally